# Microsoft Assessment and Planning knocks out SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server

We have installed MAPS onto our development machine and it has disabled one of our SQL Server 2000 instances.  We have a few instances on the server but only one is disabled.  When I say disabled, it can be accessed via the Management Tool on that machine and accessed through webpages.  However when we try to connect remotely (different machine, same domain and site) to the SQL instance, we can't.  We get an error 26 message.  Any ideas on what to check?

Answer (score 0):

Is the affected instance configured to listen on a static port number that is perhaps being used by the MAP toolkit?

If so, this:

```
netstat -ao | find "<port>"
```

Should give you the PID of the process listening on the port.

Comment: I will pass the information onto our services team and see what they come back with.

Answer (score 0):

I just had it happen to me, and it was because for some reason, the MAP installation stopped and disabled SQL Server Browser service.  I had to manually change start-up type to Automatic and restart it before everything was working again.

This should be documented somewhere, and I'm not sure why it would have to disable it in the first place.

Comment: I guess because it had to install an instance of SQL Server 2008 Express.  But that should just be temporary.  Anyways, without Browser, you won't be able to remotely access any named instances.  I suspect you were only able to access your main MSSQLSERVER instances.